# PhpStorm IDE-wide deployment settings

Tags: deployment, ide, phpstorm

I am trying to configure my IDE to save the deployment settings for my servers IDE-wide rather than project specific. I know you could do this, but can't find that setting any more.

My PhpStorm is fully up-to-date, so I'm not sure if I'm missing it somewhere or if that feature was removed.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ensure that you do not tick "Visible only for this project" option: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/deployment-connection-tab.html?search=deployment P.S. It's not going to be 100% IDE-wide as Mappings tab is per project anyway (but Connection tab will be).

Comment: Ah thanks very much!